# How to literally translate this: 随着小人书的流行，出现了从事租书业务的小人书摊?

Tags: translation, sentence-structure

随着小人书的流行，出现了从事租书业务的小人书摊，这对于那些想看又买不起书的人来说，只用很少的钱就能看一本，毫无疑问是件大好事。

This is from the Standard Course Book of HSK5, section 20.

I need your help in the literal translation of this: 随着小人书的流行，出现了从事租书业务的小人书摊

随着(following)小人书(comics)的流行(popularity)，出现了(emerged)从事(dealing with or engaging with)租书(renting book)业务(business)的小人书(comics)摊(spreading out)

How to make it (especially the second clause) make sense?

Comment: Would you be able to use the tag [tag:translation] (not *translate*)? It should automatically pop up when you're adding tags to the question.

Answer (score 1):

- 摊 here is not the verb "to spread" but a shorthand for a noun "摊位 (booth)"
- 摊 = 摊位(booth); 小人书摊 = comic books booth

随着(following)

小人书的(of comics)

流行(popularization)，

出现了(emerged)

从事(dealing with or engaging with)

租书业务的(book rental business')

小人书摊(comics book booth/stall)

> 随着小人书的流行，出现了从事租书业务的小人书摊

> Following the popularization of comics, emerged comics book booths that engaged with the book rental business

Answer (score 1):

Agree with your interpretation of the words except for 摊, which is a noun that indicates the place of buying-selling goods, such as 地攤 (a street vendor) or 報攤 (a newspaper booth/stand).

Again, rearranged grammatically:

- Following the popularity of comic books, comic book stands/booths that engage in the book rental business have emerged.